# Update of IntelliJ Idea delete shelve changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I had a lot of changes in my shelve and I had to update the IntelliJ. But after that I noticed that every single change gone. Can I restore it somehow? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Check in in the `shelf` subdirectory under the IDE Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory. Use the version where it was last available.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Use the version where it was available. What do you mean exactly by this? Where I should use it?

Comment: For example, if you were using version 2022.1 and updated to 2022.3, look in the config/shelf directory for 2022.1 version.

Comment: There's no shelf directory. So it means it lost?

Comment: Check in the project as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html#change-shelve-location.